# Put a Max value in time input (Laravel Collective)

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

Does anyone know how to put a maximum value for a time input in Laravel Collective?
I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```php
{!!Form::time('tiempo[]', 'max="04:00"')!!}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your options as the third parameter in an array. The second argument is the value of the input.

```
{!! Form::time('tiempo[]', null, ['max' => '04:00']) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks! And is there a way to the input only show hours until 4?

Comment: Since every browser [works different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Appearance) on this approach, I can't really tell. Sorry.